# How to use International place Value System on HTML TextBox

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a web app. This app has a text box. The user will enter a dollar value into the text box. As the user is typing, I would like to include commas when appropriate. In others, if a user enters "100", the text will appear as entered. However, if the user enters "1000", I would like to automatically convert the text in the text box to show "1,000".

Is there a plugin to help with this? I'm having problems finding one. I'm using Bootstrap.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know plugin but you can write it in javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope The below Code will help you

```
var x=123456524578;
x=x.toString();

var res = x.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") ;

alert(res);
```

follow the below Link

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ww9ca8f0/)

now Append the above output to your `Textbox` or wherever you want.
the logic lies above,how to use the **INTERNATIONAL PLACE VALUE SYSTEM**